# Back button after Branch Logic in Qualtrics

Tags: javascript, button, navigation, back, qualtrics

I am programming a survey in Qualtrics.
Is there any way I can allow for a Back Button after the respondent move to a certain Branch Logic? I have tried to add the JavaScript this.showPreviousButton() in the last question of the block but the button does not appear.
Any alternative solution?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It isn't possible. Qualtrics won't show the back button on the first page of a question block if there is any logic between it and the previous question block in the survey flow.

The only alternative would be to use question display logic and skip logic in place of survey flow logic.